# Unwanted space between rows within nested tables - HTML/CSS

Tags: rows, padding, html, css-tables

The following code is controlling the table properties of my webpage:

```
table, th, td
{
border:0;
border-spacing:0;
padding:0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:100px;
}
```

The problem is that the encompassing table that holds all of the parts recognizes the styles, but the nested tables continue to have space between the rows. Keep in mind that the sliced images in each vertical column make up the same height in pixels as the rest of the columns, so I don't think it's a size issue. I was able to put all this together fine in Dreamweaver, but there continues to be space between rows when I write it myself.

Is this type of a thing a common problem when nesting tables? Could anything else on the page be keeping these rows from coming together?

And in case you would ask, I'm slicing these images up at all so I can create rollover buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the solution I found was to add "img" to the table style properties:

```
table, th, td, **img**
{
border:0;
border-spacing:0;
padding:0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `border-collapse:collapse;` to your style

Comment: Sadly, that did nothing. I've even tried adding these style attributes to the individual nested tables and nothing changes.